# Laravel 5.4 - How to Responses JSON data with foreign key?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have two tables and I want to response data with a foreign key.

TableCategory

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id',10);
            $table->string('name',100)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

TableSong

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('songs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id',10);
            $table->string('name',100)->nullalbe();
            $table->string('url',500)->nullalbe();
            $table->integer('categories_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('categories_id')->references('id')->on('categories');

        });
    }
```

CategoryModel

```
class CategoryModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
    ];
    public function song()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SongModel::class);   
    }
}
```

SongModel

```
class SongModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'songs';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'url',
        'categories_id',
        'singers_id',
        'types_id',
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CategoryModel::class, 'categories_id');
    }
}
```

CategorySongController

```
class CategorySongController extends Controller
{

    public function index(CategoryModel $categoryModel)
    {
        $song = $categoryModel->song;
        return response()->json(['Data' => $song]);
    }

}
```

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'songs.category_model_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from
>   `songs` where `songs`.`category_model_id` is null and
>   `songs`.`category_model_id` is not null)

My routes

> Route::resource('/api/v1/categories', 'CategoryController', ['only' =>
>   ['index', 'show',]]); Route::resource('/api/v1/categories.songs',
>   'CategorySongController', ['only' => ['index']]);

Comment: replace `return $this->hasMany(SongModel::class);` with `return $this->hasMany(SongModel::class,'categories_id');`

Comment: I changed but it show me again: Use of undefined constant categories_id - assumed 'categories_id'

Comment: did you wrap categories_id with quotes ?

Comment: sorry sir, cloud you explain me more?

Comment: can you show me whole line of code you added ?

Comment: oh, I understand your mean that wrap categories_id with  single quotes right?

Comment: yea. Are you still getting that error ?

Comment: @Divyank Munjapara, Thank you so much sir, It's working now:D

Comment: I'm adding answer below, upvote if it was useful

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `song` relationship in `CategoryModel` Model, you current method will try to find  `category_model_id` in `songs` table because you didn't provide any foreign key in you relationship

replace `return $this->hasMany(SongModel::class);` with return `$this->hasMany(SongModel::class,'categories_id');` to fix your error

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of your method `song()` in the CategoryModel to plural `songs()`.